# SQL ошибка при создани

Tags: sql

Проблема при создании таблицы в '5.7.12-0ubuntu1'

```
CREATE TABLE `staff` (
    `workstat_start` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `workstat_end` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `is_operator` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `is_contract` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `contract_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `is_asbi` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    `dismiss_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `additional_data` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=15;
```

код ошибки

```
Error Code: 1067. Invalid default value for 'workstat_start'
```

Comment: MySQL workbench

Comment: А зачем вам такие дефолты?

Comment: По документации всё ОК

Answer (score 2, accepted):

по документации вот:

> NO_ZERO_DATE
>
> The NO_ZERO_DATE mode affects whether the server permits '0000-00-00'
>   as a valid date. Its effect also depends on whether strict SQL mode is
>   enabled.
>
> If this mode is not enabled, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts
>   produce no warning.
>
> If this mode is enabled, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts produce
>   a warning.
>
> If this mode and strict mode are enabled, '0000-00-00' is not
>   permitted and inserts produce an error, unless IGNORE is given as
>   well. For INSERT IGNORE and UPDATE IGNORE, '0000-00-00' is permitted
>   and inserts produce a warning.

в 5.7 в Ubuntu по дефолту включена эта настройка

решается, по идее так: `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` и `NO_ZERO_DATE` в конфиге сервера, точнее меняешь настройки по дефолту на

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

p.s. про вопрос в комментах, `а почему бы даты не делать NULL`  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723367/whats-the-point-of-not-null-default

Comment: Спасибо за помощь времени не било чтоб играться поставил себе '5.6.31'