# Mysql: переезд с 5.6 на 5.7

Tags: mysql

На домашнем компьютере у меня запущен mysql. Для обновления (с переустановкой) я сделал бэкап `/var/lib/mysql`. Теперь я поставил mysql 5.7, ранее стояла 5.6. Как правильно импортировать старые базы из бэкапа?
UPD: судя по ответу, у меня именно "мигрировать базу" надо.

Comment: mysql сам апгрейдит базы. зачем их импортировать?

Comment: @strangeqargo: Если так, то напишите ответ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

в современных линуксах mysql при апгрейде сам занимается миграцией бд ([пруф](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/upgrade-mysql-5-5-to-5-6-ubuntu-14-04?answer=19424))

поэтому, хотя бэкап перед апгрейдом и стоит сделать, но волноваться о "миграции бд" нужно только если

1. вы зачем-то перенесли куда-то файлы базы данных и теперь думаете, как мигрировать их из бэкапа
2. обнаружили внезапные ошибки при работе с новой версией mysql

в первом случае - можно использовать скрипт миграции, но, имхо, чтобы не ломать себе голову, проще снести новый mysql, поставить старый, скопировать файлы бд в старую локацию и опять накатить новый mysql.

возможно (и было бы не удивительно) если mysqld  сам проверяет версии файлов и сам их мигрирует без всяких скриптов - я не проверял - если получится - проверьте и сообщите

[классический](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/copying-databases.html) способ переноса (и, фактически, миграции) баз данных плох только тем, что в 5.7, насколько я помню, изменились дефолты при работе с датами (см [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/533113/208216)), поэтому при миграции этим способом из старых версий mysql могут возникнуть проблемы.

если вам приходится мигрировать базы данных размером более 1GB, возможно вам следует подумать об усложненной схеме -

- допустим, два дополнительных сервера/инстанса mysql, оба получают данные по репликации, у вас получается автобэкап.
- при апгрейде вы мигрируете базы на запасном сервере, туда докатываются данные по репликации со старого сервера,
- вы переключаете продакшен на новый сервер и апгрейдите старый. получается практически нулевой простой сервиса.
- третий инстанс реплицирует с отставанием, допустим, на 15 минут, таким образом, если кто-нибудь по глупости или со зла запустит drop databse, у вас будет время спасти свежие данные. Другое дело, что, допустим, у вордпресса не должно быть прав на drop database, но тем не менее, если кто-то получил доступ к ssh, то есть вероятность, что он сможет вытащить и пароли к бд

правда, если у вас есть большие базы, вам уже пора задуматься о найме DB-админа